# GMSMapView zoom around a fixed point on the screen

Tags: objective-c, macos, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

This code will displace a marker 100 pixels lower down on the screen:

```
CGPoint point = [myMapView.projection pointForCoordinate:marker.position];
point.y -= 100.0f;
GMSCameraUpdate *camera = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:[myMapView.projection coordinateForPoint:point]];
[myMapView animateWithCameraUpdate:camera];
```

I'd also like to zoom in at the same time. Can anyone help with offseting and zooming in the same animation - that is zooming around a displaced (non-centre) point on the screen. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where you need to zoom on coordinate position or point ?

Comment: a (non-centre) point on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use bellow code for zoomin mapview

```
 GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:@"12.234"
                                                        longitude:@"77.534"
                                                             zoom:15];
```

Comment: This moves the centre of the map to coordinate 12.234, 77.534 and then zooms based on that. I need to zoom based on a non-centre or offset point on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to do this by setting the GSMapView padding parameter, thereby offsetting the map's centre before doing the camera zoom.